# How to resolve errors on @Id fields, when @Column(name = "foo") annotation does not match field name

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I seem to be having trouble when I define a field on an entity with @Id, and also have a @Column annotation which does not match the field name. i.e.

```
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "foo")
    private Long id;

   ...   
}
```

When I attempt to persist this using the repository save() method, I get:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationExeption
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException
Integrity constraint violation: 
    NOT Null check constraint; SYS_CT_10083 table: MyEntity column ID
```

If the name in the @Column annotation is changed to "id" (to match the field name and getId() accessor), then it works perfectly.

This is happening in a test, where I have created an embedded H2 or HSQL database (I tried both) from my entities.

With a dig through logs, I can see that the table is being created incorrectly:

```
[tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] 
create table MyEntity (
    foo bigint not null, 
    ..., 
    id integer not null, 
    primary key (id))
```

Therefore the issue seems to be with how tables are generated when there is an @Id annotation.

Does anybody have any thoughts on where I should be looking to resolve this? It seems to me that there may be a bug in either spring data or hibernate, but I'm not too sure on how best to attack the problem.

fyi - I'm using Spring 3.2.4.RELEASE, spring-data-jpa 1.3.4.RELEASE and hibernate-entitymanager 4.0.1.Final

For those who enjoy reading stack traces, an example full trace is below.

Thanks for any help anybody can provide!

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.foo.integration.repositories.JobRepositoryTest': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10083 table: JOB column: ID; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10083 table: JOB column: ID

            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)

            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:396)

            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475)

            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:388)

            at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:111)

            at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)

            at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)

            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)

            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)

            at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)

            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)

            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)

            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)

            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)

            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)

            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)

            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)

            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)

            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)

            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)

            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)

            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)

            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)

            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)

            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)

            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)

            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)

            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10083 table: JOB column: ID; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10083 table: JOB column: ID

            at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:643)

            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:106)

            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403)

            at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:58)

            at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)

            at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:163)

            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)

            at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92)

            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)

            at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)

            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)

            at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)

            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.saveAndFlush(Unknown Source)

            at com.foo.integration.repositories.JobRepositoryTest.initialiseData(JobRepositoryTest.java:31)

            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:344)

            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:295)

            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:130)

            ... 27 more

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10083 table: JOB column: ID

            at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:74)

            at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)

            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)

            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)

            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)

            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)

            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)

            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:56)

            at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2849)

            at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3290)

            at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:80)

            at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:272)

            at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:264)

            at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:186)

            at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)

            at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)

            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1081)

            at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:973)

            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241)

            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.flush(Unknown Source)

            at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.flush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:404)

            at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:372)

            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:333)

            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:318)

            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)

            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)

            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)

            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)

            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)

            at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)

            ... 42 more

Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10083 table: JOB column: ID

            at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)

            at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)

            at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)

            at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)

            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)

            ... 75 more

Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10083 table: JOB column: ID

            at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)

            at org.hsqldb.Table.enforceRowConstraints(Unknown Source)

            at org.hsqldb.Table.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source)

            at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source)

            at org.hsqldb.StatementInsert.getResult(Unknown Source)

            at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source)

            at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)

            at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)

            ... 82 more
```

Comment: Are you supplying your own value for the id field?

Comment: I am at the moment. I was using generators originally, and experienced the same issue. I dropped them and specified the value myself in the hope that by forcing the value myself (and simplifying things), things might work. Things didn't work.

Comment: Are you using a naming strategy anywhere in the config?  Are the imports all `javax.persistence...`

Comment: No custom naming strategies. Just whatever comes out of the box.

Comment: And yes, all imports are javax.persistence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having simplified the application considerably, I established that this exception was a side-effect of having 2 entities referencing the same table, where the second table *did* have a field called "id".

i.e.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
public class MyEntity {
    @Id @Column(name = "pk") private Long id;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
public class MyOtherEntity {
    @Id @Column(name = "id") private Long id;
    ...
}
```

It looks to me as though this caused Hibernate/JPA to generate and validate against a table which was a composite of the two entities, where (in the above example) "pk" and "id" were both non-null fields, and (perhaps due to being alphabetically later) the primary key was set to be the @Id of MyOtherEntity.

I'm not sure whether this is by design. Certainly, I can see that having multiple small entities referencing a huge flat table, might be useful when working with a 'legacy' database. But it certainly caught me out. Especially with the manner in which it treated the 2 separate @Id fields (both non-null, but only one primary key).

Answer (score 0):

Usually a generator is used to create the value for the id column.

Try:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "foo")
    private Long id;

   ...   
}
```

Comment: I did start out with generators, but that didn't help with the problem where the incorrect field name is being used. I took out the generator and provided the field name in the hope that by specifying the value myself, things might work for my tests. It didn't help. :-/

Comment: Are you annotating your classes with @Entity?

Comment: Yes. The entity is persisted correctly if there is no @Column annotation or its value is the same as the field name: @Column(name = "id")

Comment: Another idea would be to manually set the `id` field to a value, just for a test.  Also as suggested make sure all the imports are jpa (`javax.persistence`).  I have done this plenty of times with this tech stack, I think something simple is wrong here.

Comment: That's what I'm doing at the moment, having tried generated IDs previously. Same exception.

As mentioned, @Column(name = "id") works. The test shows that an entity instance is being inserted and that I am able to query that instance back out of the database. So the stack as such is fine. The error only occurs if I then change the name in the @Column annotation to something other than the field name in the class.